# Where/how to delete an object within another object, outside the function that it was created in

Tags: c++, object, memory, memory-leaks, delete-operator

In order to solve this problem [Bad memory management? Class member (boolean) value greater than 1, in recursion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543987/bad-memory-management-class-member-boolean-value-greater-than-1-in-recursion), I ran the whole program under Valgrind and found a few memory leak problems that occurred before the step. There were 2 'definitely lost' problems identified in the function CMFLoader.

(here MyDataset is a vector of Molecule objects, and each Molecule object contains an Elements object)

In CMFLoader::loadFile(vector& MyDataset), I originally have

```
MyDataset.push_back( readMolecule( in_file, word );
```

where CMFLoader::readMolecule returns a Molecule object. Within the readMolecule function, a new Molecule object is created (but not deleted until the very end of main, more on that later)

```
Molecule* CMFLoader::readMolecule( ifstream& in_file, string id)
{
Molecule* my_mol = new Molecule( id );
// statements, somewhere along the readFormula function is called
my_mol->setFormula( readFormula( ss ) );
return my_mol;
}
```

where CMFLoader::readFormula returns an Element object and there is a Molecule::setFormula function to save it to the Molecule object. In readFormula

```
Elements* CMFLoader::readFormula( stringstream& ss )
{
Elements* my_formula = new Elements();
...
return my_formula;
}
```

I ran into problems described in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543987/bad-memory-management-class-member-boolean-value-greater-than-1-in-recursion), later in the main program. The specific problem occurred at the HammettCheck::checkHammett step. I then changed the above CMFLoader functions to something like this. The problems I encountered earlier seems to have disappeared (but there were other problems later in the program that were no doubt related to the memory leak):

in CMFLoader::loadFile

```
Molecule* new_mol = new Molecule(word);
    MyDataset.push_back( readMolecule( in_file, word ,new_mol) );
```

where readMolecule now takes in a new argument Molecule* and the new operator is removed within the function. Similarly, in readFormula, I now have

```
 Elements* new_formula = new Elements();
my_mol->setFormula( readFormula( ss, new_formula ) );
```

etc.

Now of course the memory leak problem is not removed! However, I **cannot put in the delete operator within any of the CMFLoader functions** as the objects are used later in the main program. Specifically, Elements* is used till the ConjugationCheck::checkConjugation step, and Molecule* is used till the program ends.

Main program goes like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//initialising an empty array to store our molecules.
vector<Molecule*> MyDataset;

//Read command line inputs.
InputReader* MyInputs = new InputReader();
if( !MyInputs->readInputs(argc, argv) ) {delete MyInputs;return -1;}

//Load CMF file.
CMFLoader* MyLoader = new CMFLoader( MyInputs );
unsigned int min_same_grp = MyLoader->getmin(); //define minimum no of same hammett groups for structure
if( !MyLoader->loadFile( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyLoader;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyLoader;

cout << MyDataset.size() << " molecules loaded" << endl;

//Remove molecules which are too large.
BigFilter* MyBigFilter = new BigFilter( MyInputs );
if( !MyBigFilter->filterBigLigands( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyBigFilter;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyBigFilter;

cout << "Molecules left after big ligand filter: " << MyDataset.size() << endl;

//Mark any Hammetts groups found in molecules.
HammettCheck* MyHammettCheck = new HammettCheck(min_same_grp);
if( !MyHammettCheck->loadHammetts() ) {delete MyHammettCheck;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
if( !MyHammettCheck->checkHammett( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyHammettCheck;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyHammettCheck;

cout << "Molecules containing Hammett Groups: " << MyDataset.size() << endl;

ConjugationCheck* MyConjugationCheck = new ConjugationCheck(min_same_grp);
if( !MyConjugationCheck->checkConjugation( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyConjugationCheck;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyConjugationCheck;

cout << "Molecules containing conjugated Hammett Groups: " << MyDataset.size() << endl;

DataAdder* MyDataAdder = new DataAdder( MyInputs );
if( !MyDataAdder->addData( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyDataAdder; delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyDataAdder;

//Sorts molecules based on their NLO rating given by NLOCompare.
if (min_same_grp ==1) {sort(MyDataset.begin(), MyDataset.end(), NLOCompare);}
else {sort(MyDataset.begin(), MyDataset.end(), OctuNLOCompare);}

//Saves a new CIF file containing just the predicted NLO molecules.
FileSaver* MyFileSaver = new FileSaver( MyInputs );
if( !MyFileSaver->saveFile( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyFileSaver;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyFileSaver;

/*
Saves a txt file which can be imported into Excel, showing the
paths to each of the selected Hammett groups in a molecule.
*/
ExcelSaver* MyExcelSaver = new ExcelSaver( MyInputs );
if( !MyExcelSaver->saveFile( MyDataset ) ) {delete MyExcelSaver;delete MyInputs;return -1;}
delete MyExcelSaver;

//Cleans the memory before exiting the program.
for(unsigned int i=0; i < MyDataset.size(); i++){
    delete MyDataset[i];
}
delete MyInputs;
return 0;
}
```

At various points in the program, if the Molecule MyDataset[i] does not fit certain conditions, it is removed using

```
MyDataset.pop_back();
```

So this would call the Molecule Destructor, which looks like this

```
Molecule::~Molecule(void)
{
//Deletes all atoms in molecule.
for(unsigned int i=0; i < mol_atoms.size(); i++){
    delete mol_atoms[i];
}

//Deletes all bonds in molecule.
for(unsigned int i=0; i < mol_bonds.size(); i++){
    delete mol_bonds[i];
}

//Deletes the class of elements contained.
delete mol_formula;
}
```

**I am not sure what went wrong here. How should I fix the memory leak problem?**

The "definitely loss" problems in my Valgrind Memcheck Leak summary

```
==34809== 400 (96 direct, 304 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 33
==34809==    at 0x1000A0679: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==34809==    by 0x1000F7F04: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==34809==    by 0x10000A3B4: CMFLoader::readMolecule(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::string, Molecule*) (in ./OctuDiscovery)
==34809==    by 0x10000B9EE: CMFLoader::loadFile(std::vector<Molecule*, std::allocator<Molecule*> >&) (in ./OctuDiscovery)
==34809==    by 0x10000282E: main (in ./OctuDiscovery)

==34809== 12,833 (152 direct, 12,681 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 33 of 33
==34809==    at 0x1000A0679: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==34809==    by 0x1000F7F04: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==34809==    by 0x10000B93B: CMFLoader::loadFile(std::vector<Molecule*, std::allocator<Molecule*> >&) (in ./OctuDiscovery)
==34809==    by 0x10000282E: main (in ./OctuDiscovery)
```

Comment: That's a lot of `delete`s o_O. You should read about RAII, and specifically `unique_ptr`. All resources should be owned by automatic objects that are responsible for their lifetimes. Use the type system to ensure that you don't have any leaks.

Comment: @Mankarse I see that unique_ptr is a c++11 implementation? If I am using gcc4.2 compiler, should I use auto_ptr instead?

Comment: @disillusionsed: You could use `auto_ptr`, or you could use [boost::interprocess::unique_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.unique_ptr), or you could roll your own `unique_ptr` using [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/move.html), or you could stop using dynamic allocation for as many things -- it it totally not needed for any of the objects that you construct in `main`, for example (or anywhere in the code that you have presented, for that matter).

Comment: Also, you say at the end that popping a `Molecule*` off the `Vector` will call its destructor. I'm pretty sure it won't. It would if it were a `Vector<Molecule>`. That is very likely contributing to your memory leak.

Comment: @Dogmatixed so if I first call the destructor and then pop the vector back, that might solve my problem? say replace MyDataset.pop_back(); with delete MyDataset[i]; MyDataset.erase(MyDataset.begin()+i); ?

Comment: @disillusioned If you were to do that it might be wise to do it in the opposite order -- `Molecule* m = dataset.pop_back(); delete m;`. But, like other people have mentioned, I would recommend evaluating whether you really need to be using pointers here, or switching to smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

More a comment than an answer, but too long for a comment:
In next function, it doesn't make sense to use dynamic memory:

```
Molecule* CMFLoader::readMolecule( ifstream& in_file, string id)
{
Molecule* my_mol = new Molecule( id );
// statements, somewhere along the readFormula function is called
my_mol->setFormula( readFormula( ss ) );
return my_mol;
}
```

You could replace it with:

```
Molecule CMFLoader::readMolecule( ifstream& in_file, string id)
{
Molecule my_mol( id );
// statements, somewhere along the readFormula function is called
my_mol.setFormula( readFormula( ss ) );
return my_mol;
}
```

This solves already 1 possible memory leak, but there might be reasons why the dynamic memory version is needed/preferred, in which case the already mentioned unique_ptr should be used.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I can return the actual molecule object, as it is fairly large (contains something like a vector of Atom objects, vector of Bond objects etc). Can I use unique_ptr in a vector class?

Comment: @dillusioned: Why don't you work with const references (aliases) to Molecule objects, instead of pointers then?

Comment: About "Can I use unique_ptr in a vector class?": yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3283795/104774.  About returning a large object, this is not necessarily a problem.  Compiler optimization (NRVO) can take care that there is no copy and vectors have a small footprint on the stack, because its data is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like this, I would suggest that you take a look at std::auto_ptr class, or at least the concepts of smart pointers, or auto pointers. You should rely on RAII (Resource Aquisition Is Initialization) paradigm, meaning that the memory management should be done by objects themselves: avoid basic pointers and self written memory management code whenever you can.

Comment: But can I make a vector of auto_ptr objects? I really need to use the vector class as so much of my code is written using the vector member functions.

Comment: auto_ptr or another type of smart pointer behaves just like an object, there is no reason why you couldn't put it in any STL container. The only difference that you need to take care of is invoking STL standard algorithms on this vector, to take into account the auto_ptr type.

Comment: Question: if you have a vector of molecules, why do you need pointers to them? Why not have just a vector of molecule objects?

Comment: @tomislav-maric: "there is no reason why you couldn't put it [`auto_ptr`] in any STL container" -- this is plain wrong. `auto_ptr` has a copy constructor which acts like a move constructor, and the standard is carefully designed to make it illegal to put `auto_ptr`s in containers (there is a reason that `auto_ptr` is deprecated in favour of `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @Mankarse:you can't change the ownership of any constant auto_ptr. But I agree, if possible, use the unique_ptr. The point that I was making is just to switch from * to smart pointers.